# Problema con serializacion en java

Tags: java, serialización

Tegno un programa, en el que cada usuario tiene unos datos fijos: dni, nombre, contraseña.. y solo tiene uno que varia durante la ejecucion del programa: el saldo.

He conseguido serializar los datos fijos, cuando inicio el programa los cargo desde un dat, y cuando termina el progrmama se guardan los usuarios nuevos que he registrado. Pero con el saldo no soy capaz de hacerlo, solo se guardar el valor inicial. Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Seria bueno si agregas el codigo que usaste para serializar y para acumular el valor de la variable saldo.
Sino es demasiado amplia tu pregunta para poder responder sin adivinar...

Comment: Puesto que el saldo supongo que es un dato que varía según el consumo que se haga deberías tener un script dedicado únicamente a establecer el saldo actual . Quizá hasta deberías tener dos columnas : una saldo fijo y otra columna calculada saldo actual.  En el script que crea el usuario no puedes hacer otra cosa que asignarle un saldo inicial pero la actualización del mismo sería algo aparte y que debería ejecutarse cada vez que hay un consumo usando UPDATE usuarios SET saldo_actual=valor  WHERE id_usuario=...